# Re-position Chrome developer tools inner windows

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

My chrome developer tools are set to Vertical mode,
the CSS area is located down and the html is up:

Is there a way to replace between them?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move 'debugger' panel in Sources in Chrome DevTools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482260/move-debugger-panel-in-sources-in-chrome-devtools)

Comment: do somebody know??